# Could building a fridge next to an oven be useful?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

I read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486283/could-a-refrigeration-unit-be-used-to-provide-useful-heating) question already, but it doesn't really answer mine, as I'm not talking about the possibility to reverse a refrigerator into a heat pump: in this question, fridges will work normally.
I know that fridges and freezers have the "side effect" of heating their outside. I know that this heating effect isn't strong, but it isn't neglectable either: **could it be used for heating purposes?**
For example, preheating an oven, or giving a low (but constant) heat to floor heating? Or maybe other uses I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Remember the oven also heats the area around it, as they are not perfectly insulated, so this may heat the fridge as well...

Comment: Yes, but remember that the hotter the outside of the fridge is, the hotter the inside gets too.

Comment: Only if the oven has no heat source other than the fridge heatsink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing a refrigeration system, there are several things to consider:

1. What is the lowest temperature that you want to achieve?
2. What is the temperature of the ambient environment that you want to reject heat to?
3. How many Watts of heat do you need to reject to the environment?
4. Given several possible refrigerants, what vapor pressures correspond to the cold temperature and the hot temperature of that refrigerant?
5. Do you need a one stage or multi-stage compressor, and what is the compressor flow rate at suction conditions?
6. Etc.

The point of these questions is to point out the fact that a LOT of engineering decisions have to be made in order to design a particular refrigeration system.  Once those decisions are made, equipment is selected that will do the required job, but that equipment is then constrained to operate within its design limits.  A normal refrigeration system is designed to reject heat to ambient air, which is assumed to be in the range of 100 deg F.  With a 20 degree "approach" temperature, this means that the refrigerant condenses in the condenser coils at 120 deg F.  If you intend to operate that refrigerator such that the cold items inside the refrigerator remain at their desired temperature, you will NOT be able to obtain "heated" air at a temperature that is much higher than the assumed ambient air temperature of 100 deg F, which means that the answer is "no", you can't preheat oven air with a refrigerator.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you wrote, but now I'm wondering: what it I want to heat something to 40°C (or whatever 100°F is)? Could the "back of fridge" setup be useful in that case, since the temperature in the average house is lower than that?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti, yes, you could use the fridge to heat something to 100 deg F.  However, note that energy usage is dependent on the temperature that the refrigerant is condensing "against".  If normal ambient temperature is 75 deg F, your refrigerator will use less energy than if you force the condenser to run in a 100 deg F ambient atmosphere.  As one of my engineering professors was fond of saying, you just don't get something for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

In principle one can use waste heat for all sorts of purposes -- see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waste_heat_recovery_unit for a short description. It is often challenging to do this in such a way that the costs don't outweigh the benefits. (And, of course, this can never sidestep thermodynamics.) Specifically putting a fridge "next to" an oven is probably not a good idea -- note that as @iterrate wrote, the efficiency of the fridge will drop if its output reservoir's temperature increases.

Comment: You're right: I meant "next to" with some sort of machinery in between.